# Draw/overlay a rectangle box on top of application and capture mouse XY

Tags: delphi, draw, windowing

I have a CAD application I am trying to build a plugin for and I need to be able to select lines and arcs. I cannot directly do this from the application. In my code I want to start drawing a windowing rectangle just free hand with the mouse. Through API I can determine what lines/arcs were enclosed in the rectangle that was just drawn.

The question is, how can I just draw a rectangle from my mouse on top of another application? A left click to start the upper left corner, drag to resize, and then releasing the left click to end the rectangle? There's not really an forms involved either, so I don't know if I can use a picturebox/TCanvas or what. To me, this is like a windowing screen capture where you draw a rectangle over the part of the screen you want to save.

Comment: If you're writing a plug-in, then you're not exactly drawing on *another* application. Your plug-in is probably a DLL running within the same address space as the host application. That gives you a little more leeway.

Comment: this is true, but i still cannot directly access the entities so I can select them. this was the workaround I came up with. it seemed doable to recognize mouse clicks and locations, I would just need to visually throw a rectangle on the screen.

Comment: Draw the rectangle on the screen and then transform the given rect points from Screen to Client.

Comment: how can i draw a rectangle on the screen?

Answer (score 2):

I used to XOR draw a rectangle as proposed by fduenas and it works quite well, but this does not work smoothly on Windows Vista and 7. Also the rectangle may get partially erased if you draw over changing areas (and pieces of the rectangle will remain if you erase it afterwards).

Instead I now use a rectangular window with a rectangular hole in it. All you have to do is reposition the window. You can create and show it in **MouseDown**, reposition it in **MouseMove** and destroy it in **MouseUp**.

Set BorderStyle of TDragRectangleForm to bsNone.

```
unit FrmDragRectangle;

// TDragRectangleForm is a rectangular window with a rectangular hole.
// Only its dotted border is visible.

interface

uses
  Windows, Forms, Graphics, Classes;

type
  TDragRectangleForm = class( TForm )
    procedure FormResize( Sender : TObject );
  public
    procedure Show;
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TDragRectangleForm.Show;
begin
  // Show the window without stealing the focus from another window:
  ShowWindow( Handle , SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE );
  Visible := True;
end;

procedure TDragRectangleForm.FormResize( Sender : TObject );
const
  nBorderWidth = 1;
var
  hrgnRect1 , hrgnRect2 : HRGN;
begin
  // Make a rectangular hole in the window:
  hrgnRect1 := CreateRectRgn( 0 , 0 , Width , Height );
  hrgnRect2 := CreateRectRgn( nBorderWidth , nBorderWidth , Width - nBorderWidth , Height - nBorderWidth );

  CombineRgn( hrgnRect1 , hrgnRect1 , hrgnRect2 , RGN_DIFF );
  SetWindowRgn( Handle , hrgnRect1 , True );
  DeleteObject( hrgnRect2 );

  Canvas.Pen.Style := psDot;
  Canvas.Pen.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Rectangle( 0 , 0 , Width , Height );
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your last question in the comment section about "How you can draw a rectangle on the screen?":

You have to get the handle of the current Desktop with something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fCanvas := TCanvas.Create;
  fCanvas.Handle := GetWindowDC(0); //or CreateDC('DISPLAY', nil, nil, nil);
end;
```

NOTE: fCanvas is declared as a field of TForm1, Example:

```
Type 
  Tform1=Class(tForm)
  ...
  ...
  protected
   fCanvas: TCanvas
 End;
```

Remember you have to free the fCanvas when destroying the TForm1

```
procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fCanvas.Free;
end;
```

A complete example could be checked here: 
Its done in an old version of Delphi but it should work
http://www.delphitricks.com/source-code/graphic/draw_directly_to_the_desktop.html

Also in DelphiForFun is a practical example of how to Draw a rectangle over the screen
http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Delphi_Techniques/Canvas_Drawing.htm

Also in DelphiForfun are examples of how you can create your own drawing program for what you want to achieve.
Check:

1) Computational geometry: http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Library/geometry1.htm (excellent example of canvas drawing with the mouse)

2) Graph searching:  http://www.delphiforfun.org/Programs/Library/Graphs1.htm

BTW just to clarify, you say you're developing a plugin, so:

a) is the CAD application a 3rt party one? if it so then maybe your CAD program has already an API interface to manage plugins that interact with the ViewPort so there should be a way you can get the canvas reference of the Map viewer and also method to do the drawing of shapes.

b) Do you develope the CAD application? then if you want to add this as a plugin then you should design your API structure so when registering the plugin you can also add a way that plugin can access to the canvas of the ViewPort

JEDI VCL has some Plugin System components (TJvPlugin and TJvPluginManager) to help you build a plugin framework for your application with very easy steps.